# Sending data via Ajax from form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I need to update row in database by id using Ajax.

**My Form:**

```
<form id="update_ajax">
     <input type="text" name="name" class="test_hide">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
     <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="pure-button">
</form>
```

**My Ajax function:**

```
$("#update_ajax").on("submit", function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var dataall={'id' : id, 'name' : name};
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "update.php",
            data: dataall,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**And my php file is:**

```
if ((isset($_GET['id'])) && (isset($_GET['name']))) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
}else{
    die("Not set");
}
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "8169x5it");
$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE test SET name=:name WHERE id=:id");
$query->bindParam(':name', $name);
$query->bindParam(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
```

And I have the error that my `name` value is not set in `$_GET['name']`. And I can't understand why it's not set. Because I send it in data.

Comment: `var id = $(this).attr('id');` that's not correct [see docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: `$(this).attr('name')` will be undefined, because the form doesn't have a `name` attribute. You want `$("input[name=name]").val()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var name = $(this).attr('name');
```

`$(this)` is the form, so `$(this).attr('id')` is `"update_ajax"`, not the value of the hidden input. And `$(this).attr('name')` is undefined because the form doesn't have a `name=something` attribute. What you really want is:

```
var id = $(this).find("input[name=id]").val();
var name = $(this).find("input[name=name]").val();
```

But you can simplify it all to:

```
var dataall = $(this).serialize();
```

`serialize()` will find all the inputs in the form and return a URL-encoded string containing all their values.

Finally, you either have to change the jQuery to use `type: 'GET'`, or change the PHP to use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand.

Comment: Why When I press update it's one time updates without reloading page and second time it not work without reloading? And I need to press F5 to update data.

Comment: It sometimes work and some time not. What it could be?

Comment: The script should echo data that can be used to update the page, and the `success:` function should use it.

Comment: The whole point of AJAX is that the page isn't reloaded. You have to write Javascript that makes the changes you want to the page.

Comment: So, can I write in `success: location.reload();`? But the point of Ajax is update without reload, as I understand.

Comment: Yes, you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

What you have, http://api.jquery.com/attr/

What you wanted http://api.jquery.com/val/

Give that a shot, it should work doesn't look like any other errors in your source. If not let us know.

EDIT:

Also you change:

```
$(this).attr('id');
$(this).attr('name');
```

To

```
$("input[name=id]").val();
$("input[name=name]").val();
```

Or

```
$(this).serialize();
```

See https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ for the later

Comment: he also needs to change the selectors.